# Parsing Data inside <script>...</script> from website

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

There is a  website (http://mediametrics.ru/rating/ru/online.html), where among other tags is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  function refresh(){
    getRows("hour.tsv?page=", "1", 10000);
    updateLiveInternetCounter();
  }
  var article = 0;
  var tsv = "                       3 580   1503064650\nrussian.rt.com/ussr/news/420565-sbu-uchitelnica-ukrainskie-shkolniki-rossiya    СБУ даст правовую оценку учительнице, свозившей украинских школьников в Россию  2003    6   0   218586881   hot\nrussian.rt.com/russia/news/420578-osin-reabilitacionniy-centr  Источник: Осин помещён в реабилитационный центр для лечения алкозависимости 984 1   0   218847908   hot\nria.ru/world/20170818/1500636323.html  Поездка школьников в Россию вызвала скандал на Украине  647 0   0   218509759   \nlife.ru/t/новости/1036389 Расчленивший Порошенко в одесском СИЗО заманил её посмотреть на выводок поросят 558 -3  0   194349817   \nlife.ru/t/новости/1036406 К Земле летит крупнейший в истории астероид 533 10  -14 218511351   hot\nlife.ru/t/новости/1036375  &quot;Горите, твари&quot;. Девушка сожгла квартиру экс-любовника, застав его с подругами    515 1   0   218563876   \nrussian.rt.com/opinion/420572-sshamir-racizm-ssha Борьба за гегемонию 341 2   0   218733119   hot\nria.ru/analytics/20170818/1500623118.html  &quot;Испания не ваша&quot;. Чему удивляется Европа после теракта в Барселоне   333 0   0   218565081   \nkazanfirst.ru/online/428961   Звезда 90-х Евгений Осин пропал без вести   276 1   0   218757821   \nlife.ru/t/новости/1036397 Неопалимая. Туристка из Австралии за год пережила теракты в трёх странах Европы 261 1   0   194318792   hot\nkazanfirst.ru/online/428899    В Нижнекамске на территории детского сада нашли повешенное тело мужчины     238 1   0   218711995   hot\nren.tv/novosti/2017-08-18/k-zemle-priblizhaetsya-krupneyshiy-so-vremeni-nablyudeniy-asteroid   К Земле приближается крупнейший со времени наблюдений астероид  205 0   0   234749571   \nmedialeaks.ru/1808qaz-mozhno-li-smeyatsya-nad-invalidami/ «Когда над нами шутят, мы чувствуем себя людьми». Можно ли смеяться над инвалидами  202 0   0   171003674   \nrussian.rt.com/inotv/2017-08-18/Die-Zeit-amerikanci-zrya-vinyat   Die Zeit: американцы зря винят Путина в беспорядках в Шарлотсвилле — ИноТВ  182 1   0   169450576   hot\nrussian.rt.com/inotv/2017-08-18/Polskij-ekspert-AES-v-Ostrovce Польский эксперт: АЭС в Островце увеличит зависимость Белоруссии от России — ИноТВ  170 0   0   171831971   hot\nproufu.ru/news/society/v_ufe_gostinyy_dvor_nazval_video_s_seksom_na_svoey_territorii_vyzyvayushchim_fleshmobom/    В Уфе «Гостиный двор» назвал видео с сексом на своей территории «вызывающим флешмобом»  164 1   0   214117541   \nria.ru/incidents/20170818/1500638674.html В Москве нашли пропавшего певца Евгения Осина   157 0   0   218897431   hot\nastravolga.ru/vnimanie-v-astraxani-propala-15-letnyaya-devochka/   Внимание, в Астрахани пропала 15-летняя девочка 146 0   0   48903255    \nrussian.rt.com/russia/news/420585-putin-pribyl-sevastopol Путин прибыл в Севастополь  146 2   -17 218748054   hot\nrg.ru/2017/08/18/samye-populiarnye-iphone-rezko-podesheveli-v-rossii.html  Самые популярные iPhone резко подешевели в России   137 0   0   234847900   hot\nrg.ru/2017/08/18/v-kieve-nazvali-stoimost-plana-marshalla-dlia-ukrainy.html    В Киеве назвали стоимость &quot;плана Маршалла&quot; для Украины    134 0   0   234794397   hot\neg.ru/society/374220/  Российский турист умер в Турции 126 0   0   218717203   \nrg.ru/2017/08/18/nasa-florence.html   Один из крупнейших астероидов в истории наблюдений сблизится с Землей   123 0   0   218573867   hot\neg.ru/showbusiness/374192/ Корчевникова опозорили перед Малаховым на «России 1»    117 0   0   234811413   \n76.ru/text/newsline/333398376001536.html  Смертельное ДТП на Октябрьском мосту: грузовик задавил дорожного рабочего   115 1   -1  194435595   \ntvzvezda.ru/news/vstrane_i_mire/content/201708181539-cyju.htm К Земле несется крупнейший за всю историю наблюдений астероид   114 -1  1   218487821   \nvesti.ru/doc.html?id=2922457  Дикие лошади развлекались, скатываясь на спинах со склона горы. Видео   101 1   0   234642168   hot\nlipetskmedia.ru/news/view/88764-Na_pohoroni.html   На похороны погибшей девушки липчане собрали более 18 тысяч рублей  96  1   0   218574664   hot\ntvzvezda.ru/news/vstrane_i_mire/content/201708181554-e4s9.htm  Эксперт рассказал о приходе к власти в Европе пророссийских политиков   91  0   -1  218830517   hot\nwww.gtrk.tv/novosti/55102-propavshaya-davlekanovo-devochka-naydena-zhivoy  Пропавшая в Давлеканово девочка найдена живой   91  -1  1   218739685   \nura.news/news/1052301050  Житель Свердловской области покончил с собой в прямом эфире. ВИДЕО  88  2   -1  234817985   \nlife.ru/t/новости/1036380 Как в разных городах мира усиливают меры безопасности после терактов с авто 87  0   1   218838043   hot\nren.tv/novosti/2017-08-18/s-miru-po-nitke-pensionerka-iz-peterburga-nazanimala-u-druzey-41-mln-rubley  С миру по нитке: пенсионерка из Петербурга назанимала у друзей 41 млн рублей    85  0   0   218509789   \ntvzvezda.ru/news/vstrane_i_mire/content/201708181514-i7xl.htm «Мишка косолапый» теперь вне закона в Латвии    84  1   0   218513398   \nwww.gazeta.ru/culture/news/2017/08/18/n_10452236.shtml    Источник рассказал о местонахождении Евгения Осина  83  1   -36 218518430   hot2\nkazanfirst.ru/online/428993   Эксперт ФАР о спорном ДТП в Казани: Вина водителя Kia очевидна — ехал на красный    82  1   1   218880995   \nren.tv/novosti/2017-08-18/propavshiy-pevec-osin-pokinul-kvartiru-s-neizvestnymi-lyudmi    Пропавший певец Осин покинул квартиру с неизвестными людьми 79  0   0   234841693   \nufa1.ru/text/newsline/333393980350464.html    В Уфе на переходе сбили девочку 77  1   0   194407135   \nprogorod76.ru/auto/21614  На Юбилейном мосту в Ярославле насмерть сбили дорожного рабочего    75  0   -1  234854112   \nprogorod33.ru/news/36433  Появилась полная программа празднования Дня города  74  0   1   234718524   \nprogorod43.ru/news/49747  Актер Павел Прилучный сделал подарок на свадьбу паре из Кирова  74  0   0   234650106   hot\nnews-front.info/2017/08/18/aleksandr-rodzhers-kriptovalyuty-eto-kidalovo/  Криптовалюты – это кидалово. Александр Роджерс  74  0   1   218498560   \nkazanfirst.ru/online/428881   Житель Нижнекамска получил 21 год колонии за двойное убийство   73  0   0   234753059   \nrussian.rt.com/inotv/2017-08-18/La-Croix-sankcii-i-ekonomicheskij La Croix: санкции и экономический рост ведут россиян в Мекку — ИноТВ    73  0   0   86929708    hot\nlife.ru/t/новости/1036381  Актёр из &quot;Бандитского Петербурга&quot; задержан за перестрелку во время игры в покер   70  -1  0   218675365   \nwww.gazeta.ru/culture/news/2017/08/18/n_10451966.shtml    Актер из сериала «Твин Пикс» арестован по подозрению в попытке убийства 69  0   0   192755461   hot\ntverigrad.ru/publication/samolety-iz-migalovo-perestanut-letat-nad-tveryu  Самолеты из Мигалово перестанут летать над Тверью   66  1   -30 234670474   hot2\nnews-front.info/2017/08/18/dmitrij-lekuh-amerikanskaya-shajtan-truba-dlya-ukrainy-s-polnym-razoblacheniem/    Американская «шайтан-труба» для Украины с полным разоблачением. Дмитрий Лекух   66  0   1   234781181   hot\nulpravda.ru/rubrics/soc/dvoe-ulianovtsev-popali-v-bolnitsu-s-podozritelnym-virusom Двое ульяновцев попали в больницу с подозрительным вирусом  66  0   1   218859103   \nren.tv/novosti/2017-08-18/propavshiy-pevec-osin-okazalsya-v-reabilitacionnom-centre   &quot;Пропавший&quot; певец Осин нашелся в реабилитационном центре  65  0   0   234843766   hot\n";
  setTZ(837);
  handleRows(tsv, 10000);   
//-->
</script>
```

Data needed to be parsed is contained in var tsv.

How to get it in proper way? It has the following structure:

> number; number
>   string string number number number number
>   string string number number number number
>   etc

I tried to use csv library, split method. No success.

That's how I get to the tag(using Beautiful Soup):

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
```

Comment: show how do you access that "website" tags

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, added info

Comment: @t.m.adam sorry, fixed

Comment: Beautifulsoup can't parse js. I think you'll have to use regular expressions.

Comment: Are you sure the data you pasted is in the same format? It does not contain any tab characters. What is the URL?

Comment: @MartinEvans here is the URL http://mediametrics.ru/rating/ru/online.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data from the URL is in correct TSV format, but the tabs appear to have got lost when you created your question. As suggested, you would need to extract the TSV information manually from within the `<script>` tag. This can be done as follows using a regular expression:

```
import re

script = """<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function refresh(){
        getRows("online.tsv?page=", "1", 10000);
        updateLiveInternetCounter();
    }
    var article = 0;
    var tsv = "                     251 1503076700\nrussian.rt.com/world/article/420644-postpred-poroshenko-krym-reakciya   «Производитель пустоты»: как в России отреагировали на назначение постпреда Порошенко в Крыму   144 1   0   49407723    \nwww.gazeta.ru/social/news/2017/08/18/n_10452926.shtml На западе Германии неизвестный напал с ножом на людей   87  0   0   190069496   \nria.ru/world/20170818/1500660543.html Совершивший теракт в Барселоне водитель ликвидирован, сообщили СМИ  81  0   0   195367053   \nrussian.rt.com/world/news/420651-nyt-tramp-uvolit-sovetnik    NYT: Трамп уволит советника по стратегическим вопросам  49  2   0   168793493   hot\nwww.iz.ru/634536/2017-08-18/mid-rf-schitaet-predatelstvom-pozitciiu-izrailia-po-muzeiu-sobibor МИД РФ считает предательством позицию Израиля по музею «Собибор»    23  2   -1  234715661   \ne1.ru/news/475053 &quot;С улицы доносились истошные крики&quot;: екатеринбурженка сняла на видео последствия теракта в Барселоне  21  -1  1   197918237   \nvedomosti.ru/technology/articles/2017/08/18/730176-navalnii-razreklamiroval   Навальный разрекламировал приложение Life   17  1   0   218535026   \nwww.gazeta.ru/social/news/2017/08/18/n_10453070.shtml Жертвами атаки неизвестного с ножом в Финляндии стали два человека  16  0   -3  218508102   hot\nrussian.rt.com/sport/news/420618-dzyuba-zenit-arenda   Дзюба может покинуть «Зенит» до закрытия трансферного окна  12  0   -7  192425429   hot\nhardnews.info/business-insider-ssha-grozyat-raznesti-floty-rossii-i-kitaya-v-pux-i-prax/   Business Insider: США грозят разнести флоты России и Китая «в пух и прах»   12  0   0   218803848   \nkaspyinfo.ru/astrahanec-ubil-zhenu-teshhu-i-zastrelilsja-na-glazah-4-letnej-docheri/  Астраханец убил жену, тещу и застрелился на глазах 4-летней дочери  12  0   -12 234822535   hot\nlenta.ru/news/2017/08/18/life_is_life/ СМИ сообщили о закрытии телеканала Life 11  0   -2  193315193   hot\nwww.smolensk2.ru/story.php?id=80338    С завтрашнего дня в Смоленск ограничат движение автотранспорта  11  0   -14 218658636   hot\nwww.mk.ru/social/2017/08/18/druzya-vydvinuli-novuyu-versiyu-smerti-very-glagolevoy.html    Друзья выдвинули новую версию смерти Веры Глаголевой    11  0   0   234743805   \nrussian.rt.com/ussr/news/420647-mid-ukrainskih-tehnologii-kndr    МИД: вопрос украинских технологий в КНДР будут ставить в международных организациях 10  0   0   218535970   \nwww.tass.ru/mezhdunarodnaya-panorama/4490566  Без зарплаты, но с помощниками: первая леди Франции определилась со своим статусом  10  0   1   218597745   \nwww.novorosinform.org/news/73454  Украинские военные расстреляли офицера и покинули позиции   10  0   0   218671838   \nvesti.ru/doc.html?id=2922568  Исполнитель барселонского теракта был убит в Камбрильсе 10  0   0   218775420   \nren.tv/novosti/2017-08-18/tramp-snimaet-s-dolzhnosti-starshego-pomoshchnika-i-glavnogo-stratega   Трамп снимает с должности старшего помощника и главного стратега    9   1   -1  234856496   \nwww.finanz.ru/novosti/aktsii/inostrancy-obyavili-boykot-rossiyskim-akciyam-1002269234 Иностранцы объявили бойкот российским акциям    9   0   1   218615204   \n76.ru/text/newsline/333475534360576.html  Участок трассы М-8 в Ярославской области полностью перекроют    9   2   -10 218520098   hot\nkbereg.info/ubita-uchitel-nitsa-nachal-ny-h-klassov-v-stanitse-pereyaslovskoj/ Убита учительница начальных классов в станице Переясловской | Кубанский берег: Брюховецкая информационно-аналитическая газета, Брюховецкий район    9   0   1   234712792   \nrussian.rt.com/document/59971c3c183561d84d8b4567/amp/420651-nyt-tramp-uvolit-sovetnik NYT: Трамп уволит советника по стратегическим вопросам  8   0   0   218641752   hot\nwww.mk.ru/moscow/2017/08/18/v-moskve-otoshedshiy-spravit-nuzhdu-yunosha-obnaruzhil-dva-trupa.html  В Москве отошедший справить нужду юноша обнаружил два трупа 8   0   -1  218857879   \ntumix.ru/auto/news/27900/v-tyumeni-inspektoryi-gibdd-operativno-dostavili-v-bolnitsu-rebenka-istekayuschego-krovyu    В Тюмени инспекторы ГИБДД оперативно доставили в больницу ребенка, истекающего кровью   8   -1  1   193807259   \nlife.ru/t/новости/1036464 Московская биржа с 21 августа приостановит торги украинской гривной 7   0   1   218721441   \nvz.ru/news/2017/8/18/883380.html  МИД назвал позицию Израиля по «Собибору» «граничащей с предательством»  7   0   0   218596041   hot\nvesti.ru/doc.html?id=2922573   &quot;Бандитский Петербург&quot;: актер Сергей Козик арестован за покушение на убийство 7   0   -15 218790608   hot\nlenta.ru/news/2017/08/18/hryvna/   Московская биржа объявила о приостановке торгов гривной 7   0   0   218519502   \nrussian.rt.com/world/news/420649-zhertvy-terakt-ispaniya-15   Число жертв теракта в Испании возросло до 15    6   0   0   172262407   hot\nwww.mk.ru/social/2017/08/18/znakomyy-evgeniya-osina-nazval-prichinu-ego-pokhishheniya.html Знакомый Евгения Осина назвал причину его &quot;похищения&quot; 6   0   -1  218882064   hot\nvedomosti.ru/finance/news/2017/08/18/730174-ostanovit-grivna-rubl  Московская биржа остановит торги парой гривна-рубль 6   0   0   87615736    \nklg.aif.ru/society/family/zabyli_doch_na_kladbishche_pochemu_roditelyam_net_dela_do_svoih_zhe_detey   Забыли дочь на кладбище. Почему родителям нет дела до своих же детей    6   2   -11 218583454   hot\nwww.gazeta.ru/business/2017/08/18/10837388.shtml   Литва придумала план спасения Украины   6   0   1   218634877   \neg.ru/culture/374339/ Спецборт с телом Веры Глаголевой прилетел в Москву  6   0   -17 218809193   \nria.ru/politics/20170818/1500661787.html  Позиция Израиля по &quot;Собибору&quot; граничит с предательством, уверены в МИД    5   0   -4  218881664   \nwww.tvrain.ru/news/dva_cheloveka_pogibli_v_rezultate_napadenija_v_finskom_gorode_turku-442512/    Два человека погибли в результате нападения в финском городе Турку  5   0   3   234854031   \nhardnews.info/kak-eto-my-umudrilis-vbuxat-v-ukrainu-sto-milliardov-i-ne-poluchit-nichego-semen-bagdasarov/    «Как это мы умудрились вбухать в Украину сто миллиардов — и не получить ничего?», — Семен Багдасаров    5   0   2   218607388   \nwww.rusvesna.su/news/1503075505   В ДНР прокомментировали строительство Украиной газопровода в обход Республики   5   0   4   218603308   \nwww.mk.ru/amp/social/2017/08/18/druzya-vydvinuli-novuyu-versiyu-smerti-very-glagolevoy.html   Друзья выдвинули новую версию смерти Веры Глаголевой    5   0   -1  218552173   \nwww.kaibicy.ru/ru/component/k2/item/14376-nevesta-brosila-buket-v-reku-no-cherez-sekundu-ee-ohvatil-uzhas-kogda-ona-uvidela-etovideo.html Невеста бросила букет в реку. Но через секунду ее охватил ужас, когда она увидела это…Видео - Кайбыч таңнары    4   0   1   218546204   \nwww.gazeta.ru/culture/2017/08/18/a_10837412.shtml Оби-Ван Кеноби наносит ответный удар    4   0   0   218511666   \nren.tv/novosti/2017-08-18/voditelya-furgona-sbivshego-lyudey-v-centre-barselony-likvidirovali Водителя фургона, сбившего людей в центре Барселоны, ликвидировали  4   0   -2  218897064   \ntumix.ru/news/27896/po-puti-v-tyumen-propala-17-letnyaya-mama-s-rebenkom  По пути в Тюмень пропала 17-летняя мама с ребенком  4   0   -10 218809100   hot\nwww.politnavigator.net/v-kieve-raskryli-rot-i-zhdut-ot-evropy-5-milliardov-evro-ezhegodno.html В Киеве раскрыли рот и ждут от Европы 5 миллиардов евро ежегодно    4   0   -1  218667935   \nura.news/articles/1036271876  Отборные слухи о лучших людях России    4   0   -1  218833842   \nvz.ru/society/2017/8/18/883364.html   Коверканье русских имен в странах бывшего СССР действительно стало проблемой    3   -1  2   194242570   \nwww.geo.ru/putesestvia/231415-15-lucsih-graffiti-benksi   15 лучших граффити Бэнкси | Geo - Непознанный мир: Земля    3   0   0   189887590   \nwww.echo.msk.ru/news/2039556-echo.html    \'Новая газета\': Подписавших обращение к генпрокурору Чайке чеченцев сгоняют на \'акцию покаяния\' в центре Грозного   3   0   0   218488956   \nvedomosti.ru/politics/news/2017/08/18/730180-kiev-moskve-notu-protesta    Киев направил Москве ноту протеста из-за поездки Путина в Крым  3   0   -1  48969894    hot\n";
    setTZ(1038);
    handleRows(tsv, 10000);


//-->
</script>>"""

tsv = re.search(r'tsv = "(.*)"', script, re.S).group(1).splitlines()
numbers = tsv[0].split("\t")
data = [row.split('\t') for row in tsv[1:]]

print numbers
print data[0]    # display the first row
```

Which would give you the following type of output:

```
['251', '1503076700']
['russian.rt.com/world/article/420644-postpred-poroshenko-krym-reakciya', '\xc2\xab\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbf\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b\xc2\xbb: \xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba \xd0\xb2 \xd0\xa0\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0 \xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb2 \xd0\x9a\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbc\xd1\x83', '144', '1', '0', '49407723', '']
```